# Edge: browserAction.setIcon not working when using a default icon with multiple sizes

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, browser-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

I can't get `browser.browserAction.setIcon` to work in Microsoft Edge when `manifest.json` is specifying a default icon in multiple sizes:

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "John Doe",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icon.png",
      "38": "icon2.png"
    }
  }
}
```

background.js

```
setInterval(function() {
  browser.browserAction.setIcon({
      path: "testimage.png"
  });
}, 2000);
```

No error logged, the code is executed but the icon doesn't change. The same code works fine in Chrome.

Changing the manifest.json to

```
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png"
}
```

Fixes the issue, but what if I need to use multiple default icons?

#### EDIT:

Unfortunately not even `"default_icon": "icon.png"` is usable, even though Edge happily loads the extension, when submitting it to the store, the validation fails with

> Validation failed: Invalid type: string (expected object)
> Schema location: /properties/browser_action/allOf/0/properties/default_icon/type
> Manifest location: /browser_action/default_icon
> Validation failed for extension manifest: Extension\manifest.json

Which is indeed what MDN says: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/browser_action#Browser_compatibility

> 'default_icon' must be an object, with explicit sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I came to the conclusion that Edge doesn't like `string` values for the browser action icon path, neither in `manifest.json` nor in `browserAction.setIcon`, it fails silently without producing any error.

A way to make it work is to always set explicit sizes in both `manifest.json` and in every `browserAction.setIcon` call, even if the different sizes all point to the same image.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "John Doe",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icon.png",
      "38": "icon2.png"
    }
  }
}
```

background.js

```
browser.browserAction.setIcon({
    path: {
      "19": "testimage.png",
      "38": "testimage.png"
});
```

Comment: That is correct. Your old method is unsupported for this reason in the link provided. See here on why you can't use "strings" format for setting the icons. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/supported-manifest-keys#browser_action-or-page_action-keys