# Microsoft Edge Extension not showing icon in context menu when browser action not visible in address bar

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge-extension

I created a small extension for Microsoft Edge. It offers a right-click context menu item on certain elements. However, I noticed that the extension icon doesn't show up in the context menu if I don't have the browser action icon in the address bar. (The "show next to address bar" option) Not even the default icon is shown, it's just completely blank.

My manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "author": "",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "20": "images/icon.svg",
      "40": "images/icon.svg"
    },
    "default_title": "",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon.svg",
    "32": "images/icon.svg",
    "64": "images/icon.svg",
    "128": "images/icon.svg"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "storage"
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
}
```

The relevant code in my background.js:

```
browser.contextMenus.create({
    id: "",
    title: "Image",
    contexts: ["image"]
});
```

Windows version: 1809, Build: 17763.1
Edge version: 44.17763.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you let us know your Win10 and Edge versions.

However, this problem doesn't exist on Win10 build (**17763.1**).

Here is my manifest.json:

```
    {
      "name": "test",
      "author": "",
      "version": "1.0",
      "description": "",
      "icons": {
        "16": "icons/icon.png",
        "32": "icons/icon.png",
        "64": "icons/icon.png",
        "128": "icons/icon.png"
      },

      "permissions": [
        "contextMenus",
        "storage"
      ],

      "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
      }

}
```

Background Script:

```
browser.contextMenus.create({
  id: "log-selection",
  title: "Sample",
  contexts: ["selection"]
}, onCreated);

function onCreated() {
    console.log("Context Menu item was created");
}
```

Let us also know your Context Menu item creation code from Background Script.

Comment: I added the missing information to my original question.
From what I can tell everything looks the same as in your setup.
I just realized that there is a default icon but this isn't shown either. It's just completely empty space.

Comment: Can you also check if your image files are all good. I am also not sure if SVGs are supported on edge. Can you use PNG instead?

Comment: Using PNGs instead of SVG seems to do the trick.
However, this seems to be a bug rather then not supporting SVG in general because the icons showed up everywhere except for the context menu and even there it worked under certain circumstances.
Edit: according to this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/design#icons Edge extensions don't support SVGs.

Comment: There is quite a few issues with Edge Extensions platform. This could be one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set explicit sizes in both **manifest.json** and in every **browserAction.setIcon** call may help you to solve the issue.

Example:

Manifest.json

```html
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "demo_user",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icon.png",
      "38": "icon2.png"
    }
  }
}
```

In JS file

```html
browser.browserAction.setIcon({
    path: {
      "19": "testimage.png",
      "38": "testimage.png"
});
```

Reference:

[Edge: browserAction.setIcon not working when using a default icon with multiple sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271670/edge-browseraction-seticon-not-working-when-using-a-default-icon-with-multiple)

You can try to make a test on your side and let us know about your testing result.

Comment: Thank you, but I already specify explicit sizes in the manifest.json. I don't change the icon at runtime so I don't use a browserAction.setIcon() but even if I add it, the problem persists. The strange thing is that this only happens if the extension is not shown in the address bar.