# responsive chrome extension icons

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, responsive-design, responsive

So google chrome extensions now require icons 16x16, 19x19, 38x38, 48x48, and 128x128 px size.

I have included the icons in my zipped file, but how do I adjust my code to make the icons responsive and display the correct size.

Currently I have the following code that points to the icon image:

```
`if(toggle.checked)

{
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"green_icon.png"
});`
    else
{
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"red_icon.png"
});
```

Obviously this code works on the basis there is one image size, so I presume need to refactor my code to make it responsive? But I can't find any google guidelines on this.

Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Example: [Edge: browserAction.setIcon not working when using a default icon with multiple sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47327572), simply use `chrome` instead of `browser`.

Comment: You can also use `chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"my_icon.svg"})`, using a SVG image that will scale automatically.